# pass textbox value and file with jquery and ajax to another form

Tags: jquery

I can pass a textbox value to another form and I can save it in database. But I can not pass the file to another page. How can I do it?

```
<input type"text" name="txt1" id="txtName">
<input type"file" name="file1" id="myImg">
<input type"button" name="btn1" id="btnSave">
```

Comment: you cannot pass file to another page...may be you can save that file in database and try to retireve it when you are in another page

Comment: I want to save it without refresh

Comment: Use iframe for upload without refresh, or there's nice plugin dropzone which can make you things easier and beautifull.

Comment: thanks thanks thanks